# Value recieved on server differs from value sent in POST request

Tags: reactjs, spring, rest

I am sending a POST request from my React front end using axios like this:

```
const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log(isPurchase);
    if (activeItem.id) {
      Axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: CREATE_TRANSACTION,
        data: {
          ...activeItem,
          isPurchase: isPurchase,
          purchaseAmount: 150,
        },
      })
        .then((res) => console.log(res))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  };
```

When I click the button that calls this function, `true` gets printed to my console.
When I check the network tab in my browser, isPurchase is true.

But the back end always gets `false`.

```
    @PostMapping("/api/create-transaction")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> createTransaction(@RequestBody TransactionModel transactionModel, Principal principal) {
        System.out.println(transactionModel.isPurchase());
        try {
            transactionService.createPurchase(transactionModel, accountService.findByUsername(principal.getName()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error when creating transaction: " + e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

All the other values of TransactionModel are valid and same as data from front end, but for some reason the isPurchase is always false...

I checked with debugger just in case, and it is indeed false.

Here's the TransactionModel:

```
@ToString
@Getter
public class TransactionModel extends ItemModel{
    private boolean isPurchase;
    private long purchaseAmount;
}
```

I am using Lombok for the @Getter and @ToString annotations. As I said, all the data from ItemModel and the purchaseAmount field are valid and are what I am expecting them to be. Why is isPurchase always false??

Answer (score 0):

Rename `isPurchase` into `purchase` so that lombok will create a `setPurchase()` setter.

Rename it also `purchase` in React.

Naming a boolean `isPurchase` is a bad practice coz the getter will have to be `isIsPurchase` !!